# JavaFX missing Legend class

Tags: java, javafx

I have this code:

```
List<Node> legends = new ArrayList<>(lineChart.lookupAll("Label.chart-legend-item"));
Legend legend1 = (Legend)legends.get(0);
```

The problem is that my IDE can't find any `Legend` class to import it.

I'm talking about this class: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#legend

I'm using Java 10. Why my IDE don't find `Legend` class?

What I want to achieve is to take the name of legend.

Comment: What is the error that you get in console or terminal?

Comment: @LazarNikolic `java: cannot find symbol` Because first I need to import `Legend` class, but my IDE see no class.

Comment: @trilogy I know what `Platform.runLater` do and in my question is just a simple example. What is the connection between runtime and I can't compile my code, because I can't import `Legend`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `Legend` is from an internal api:

`import com.sun.javafx.charts.Legend;`

Probably removed in Java9+

Comment: Ye, it seems it was removed in JavaFX 2

Answer (score 0):

You have export the module com.sun.javafx.charts to access the Legend class as the Legend class is part of the internal API.
In IntelliJ you have to add an override to the compiler:

(Settings -->Build, Execution, Deployment --> Compiler --> Java compiler -->Override compiler parameters)

```
--add-exports=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.charts=ALL-UNNAMED
```

And in the run configuration add to the VM Options.

The import is:

`import com.sun.javafx.charts.Legend;`

Edit: It has not been removed as the accepted answer says.

Example code:

```
import com.sun.javafx.charts.Legend;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Legend legend = new Legend();
        Legend.LegendItem legendItem = new Legend.LegendItem("Test legend item");
        ObservableList<Legend.LegendItem> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(legendItem);
        legend.setItems(items);
        AnchorPane anchorPane = new AnchorPane(legend);
        Scene scene = new Scene(anchorPane, 400, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

And to compiler options add:

[image: IntelliJ]

If you use gradle you have to add the compiler option to the build.gradle too.

```
compileJava {
    options.compilerArgs += ["--add-exports=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.charts=ALL-UNNAMED"]
}
```

Comment: Now I can import it, but at compile get error: `package com.sun.javafx.charts is not visible`

Comment: I can compile it with Java 10.

Answer (score 0):

TilePane is super class of Legend.
So you can cast to TilePane.

```
List<Node> legends = new ArrayList<>(lineChart.lookupAll("Label.chart-legend-item"));
TilePane legend1 = (TilePane) legends.get(0);    
legend1.setHgap(10);
legend1.getChildren().remove(..);
...
```